# For Loop iterations controlled by properties file?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, hashmap, properties-file

I have an application that contains a `method` that is used to loop through a `Hash Map` using a `For-Loop`:

```
public void iterateHashMap(Map<Dog, List<String>> mapOfDogsAndDescriptions){

        for (Map.Entry<Dog, List<String>> entry : mapOfDogIdsAndStrings.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey().getId();
            List<String> StringList = entry.getValue();

            //do something
            }

    }
```

I want to be able to define *how many times* the loop is iterated dependent on a property in my `properties` file.

E.g. If the property is set to 3, then it only iterates through the first 3 keys in the `Hash Map`.

This is my first time using a `properties file` in a Java application, How would I do so?

Comment: Have you already managed to read that value (the ``3``) from the properties file?

Comment: No I haven't, I am just starting on solving this

Comment: "The first N" is a requirement that has a small issue. For a HashMap it the keys are unordered, so the first N is undetermined. For a TreeMap it is the first N of all sorted keys. For a LinkedHashMap it is the first N in order of adding them to the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public void iterateHashMap(Map<Dog, List<String>> mapOfDogsAndDescriptions){
    int count = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("count"));
    for (Map.Entry<Dog, List<String>> entry : mapOfDogIdsAndStrings.entrySet()) {
        if (count-- <= 0)
            break;
        String key = entry.getKey().getId();
        List<String> StringList = entry.getValue();

        //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to decrease `count`.

Comment: Yes, yes I did. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain this, I cannot follow it? Thanks

Comment: @java123999 "int count" is a variable that tells us how many interations we should do. It is initialized with value read from default properties file, which is parsed using Integer.parseInt() method. After that we enter the loop and before we do anything, we check if count is less or equal 0, and if so, we break out of the loop. I used "count--" since it both decreases count by 0, and returnes original value. This is done this way because if we used --count, we'd do one less iteration (if count is 1, it is decreased, so it's 0 now, and condition in "if" statement is true, so we execute "break"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any framework? In Spring Framework you can do it as:

```
@Resource(name = "properties")
private Properties properties;
```

And in your applicationContext:

```
<bean id="properties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:urls.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

Finally, in your method:

```
int counter = 0;

Integer limit = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("some property"));

for(//Some conditions){
    //Some code

    counter++;
    if(counter > limit) break;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but then how Do I get the loop to only iterate through the first 3 entry values in the HashMap?

Comment: Use a counter, increment 1 in each iteration, compare with the property, and then use break to get out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

In pure java you can do

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
String propFileName = "config.properties";

InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

if (inputStream != null) {
    prop.load(inputStream);
} else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
}

int cpt  = Integer.valueOf(prop.getProperty("counter"));
int cptLoop = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Dog, List<String>> entry : mapOfDogIdsAndStrings.entrySet()) {
    if (cptLoop == cpt)
        break;
    String key = entry.getKey().getId();
    List<String> StringList = entry.getValue();

    //do something
    cptLoop++;
}
```